# .htaccess: Remove everything after '/index.php'

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I've spent hours looking for the ultimate way to optimize my URLs in a way they cannot break the pages and their structure.

I first needed a way to remove the trailing slash at the end of the URL - resolved! `website.com/index.php/` used to be a problem but now the `/` at the end of the URL is gone, no matter what!

Then I found out that directories themselves can also cause problems. So I had to find a way to turn something like `website.com/page/////` to `website.com/page/`. No extra slashes. Resolved!

Now, I jumped onto the next problem. Putting something after `website.com/index.php` will cause problems. For instance: `website.com/index.php/index.php` or `website.com/index.php/abc` will not throw you a **404 error** but you will remain at the current page with all the URLs (for stylesheets and scripts) broken. Which... is not good.

I actually found a few similar problems out there but none of them really helped me resolve this case. Any help would be appreciated!

*.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Putting something after `example.com/index.php` will cause problems. For instance: `example.com/index.php/index.php` or `example.com/index.php/abc` will not throw you a 404 error

The `/<something>` that appears after a file, such as `/index.php` (duplicated) and `/abc` in the above examples is called *additional pathname information* (path-info). Whether this is permitted or not (ie. serves a 404) is, by default, dependent on the file handler. PHP permits path-info.

However, you can override this and disable path-info on all file types:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Now, any path-info appearing on the URL-path will trigger a 404. Incidentally, this would also handle requests of the form `example.com/index.php/`, that you mentioned previously and handled with mod_rewrite instead.

> ...with all the URLs (for stylesheets and scripts) broken.

That's because you are using relative URL-paths to your client-side resources. Relative URLs are always likely to be a problem when rewriting the URL. More info about that here:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
> RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]
> ```

This isn't strictly correct as I could (maliciously) add multiple slashes in the query string and send the request into a redirect loop.

To avoid matching multiple slashes in the query string you could change the *CondPattern* from the simple `//` to `\s[^?]*//+`. <sub>(Although I feel there must be a more efficient regex?)</sub>

Comment: I'm really sad about the fact that I can't give you an upvote yet but you deserve that green tick! Thank you so much! This has been torturing me since early morning, I was starting to lose hope! Once again, thank you!